# calling select query after update query with flask-sqlalchemy db.engine.execute() returns un-updated resultset

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

calling select query after update query with flask-sqlalchemy db.engine.execute()  returns un-updated resultset.

I am having python project where I am updating one row in MySQL table from flask-sqlalchemy's
`db.engine.execute()` function and then in next line I am doing `select` query for same row and sending it as response to frontend. But selected query ends old data for the same row, when I check  row in a database it is actually updated. According to my knowledge relational databse like MySQL have consistency in transactions(ACID property), it is not showing it up here.

Please guide me where I am doing wrong.

```
        else:
            name = "yoga" if name is None else name
            stmt = (update(Combination)
                    .values(name=name,description=description,result=result, quality=quality, flag=flag)
                    .where((Combination.sequence == sequence) & (Combination.subseq == subseq) & (Combination.languageId == lang_id) ))
        try:
            cur.execute(stmt)
            combination = Combination.query.filter(Combination.sequence == sequence, Combination.languageId == lang_id).first()
            res['status'] = 'success'
            res["flag"] = combination.flag
            res["name"] = combination.name
            res["description"] = combination.description
            res["result"] = combination.result
            res['quality'] = combination.quality
            res['language_id'] = lang_id
        except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
            res['status'] = 'failed'
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

What about committing after executing your statement?

Add:

```
cur.commit()
```

after:

```
cur.execute(stmt)
```